# When do I need to authenticate interactively using Azure AD in a desktop App

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Azure AD authentication in a desktop app. I have written code so that it gets token from cache and if not present then asks the user to sign in.

The access token has an expiration of 1 hour. But I am never asked to login interactively after 1 hour. The authentication acquires token silently even after 1 hour and works fine when I call graph APIs.

There is no refresh token returned from Azure sign in process.
I want to know when exactly does the token expire? When will I have to sign in by entering my credentials again?

Comment: `There is no refresh token returned from Azure sign in process.` - I don't think so that's the case. The refresh token is returned however it is never exposed in the SDK. SDK makes use of it internally. To verify, I would recommend tracing the request/response through Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using refresh tokens within your authentication code, you have a 90 day expiry using the Azure AD Defaults. Details on this can be found [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#refresh-and-session-token-lifetime-policy-properties)

Assuming you want to apply controls on Azure AD sign-in timeframes, I would suggest you apply settings for session lifespan using [Conditional Access.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime)